# Appeon Mobile - Download a File from URL

Tags: powerbuilder

Is there an option to download a file (e.g. PDF) to a mobile device from the URL (without use of the Appeon File Server on the PowerServer)?

At the moment our Appeon Mobile App is showing files from various servers/URLs inside the eon_mobile_webviewex object.
We would like to download the selected file(s) to a mobile device (iOS or Android) and email them.

I can't find any information other than download from the Appeon File Server.
Once I have it on the device I should be able to email it using the eon_mobile_awsex > of_sendmail function.

Any idea how to download a file from the URL?

Regards,
Marcin

Comment: Version numbers would help here.

Comment: The app is developed using PB 2017 R3 Build 1858. PowerServer (PB Edition) 2017 R3 Build 1880

Answer (score 0):

Appeon does not provide function for this, please try using inet.hyperlinktourl function to open pdf on browser, then send mail via browser.

inet l_inet

string ls_url = "http:/172.16.8.10/pdf/test.pdf"

l_inet = create inet

l_inet.hyperlinktourl(ls_url)

Destroy l_inet

Regards,
ZhaoKai

Comment: Thank you for the info.
I think it would be a great addition to have something like that in Appeon Mobile one day